# How can I make a "catch all other" route in vue router also catch the url when part of it matches a defined route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, vue-router

I have implemented a catch all route as is suggested here

https://medium.com/@ishoshot/page-not-found-on-reload-vuejs-netlify-c71716e97e6

however it does not catch urls which partially match a defined route. For example

```
    routes: [
{
  path: "/album/:album",
  name: "album",
  component: Album,
},
{
  path: "/",
  name: "home",
  component: Home,
},
{
  path: "/*",
  component: NotFound,
},
],
```

*mysite.com/foo* will direct to the *NotFound* component, but *mysite.com/album/foo* will direct to the *Album* component which will try to display the album 'foo' which does not exist.

The albums are hosted on sanity.

I was thinking I could handle this in the *Album* component with a redirect if the album is not found, but it would be cleaner to just go straight to the *NotFound* component if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vue3, replace this:

```
{
  path: "/*",
  component: NotFound,
}
```

with the following:

```
{
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    component: NotFound
}
```

The old catchpath '*' is no longer supported in Vue3. See the [docs](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removed-star-or-catch-all-routes) for more info on this update.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I will display a message about no data found related to field 'foo'. (Can be a table containing the text 'no data found' or simply a line of text 'no data found'). I think the solution like I just mentioned is reasonable and most of the websites I have used and are using do so.